# Change custom post type slugs, with category/taxonomy before post type name

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, seo

I'm currently working on a website which is a collective name of 2 schools. That's why I've renamed the taxonomy categories to schools. So in every post of a custom post type I can select the right school/category.

Now I have 3 custom post types in this theme.

1. Agenda
2. Schoolgids (schoolguide)
3. Vacatures (vacancies)

Everything looks like it's working good, but only the URL-structure is not the way I want it to be. The way I want it, is for example: domainname.com/schoolname/post-type/post-name. My custom post type(s) is/are looking like this:

**Post type (agenda for example):**

```
function custom_post_agenda() {
    register_post_type( 'agenda',
        array('labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Agenda', 'raadhuiswp'),
            'singular_name' => __('Agenda', 'raadhuiswp'),
            'all_items' => __('Alle agendapunten', 'raadhuiswp'),
            'add_new' => __('Nieuw agendapunt', 'raadhuiswp'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Voeg nieuw agendapunt toe', 'raadhuiswp'),
            'edit' => __( 'Wijzig', 'raadhuiswp' ),
            'edit_item' => __('Wijzig agendapunt', 'raadhuiswp'),
            'new_item' => __('Voeg nieuw agendapunt toe', 'raadhuiswp'),
            'view_item' => __('Toon agendapunt', 'raadhuiswp'),
            'search_items' => __('Zoeken naar agendapunten', 'raadhuiswp'),
            'not_found' =>  __('Niks gevonden in de database.', 'raadhuiswp'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('Niks gevonden en de prullenbak.', 'raadhuiswp'),
            'parent_item_colon' => ''
            ),
            'description' => __( 'Een post type voor agendapunten', 'raadhuiswp' ),
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'menu_position' => 8,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-calendar-alt',
            'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => '%school%/agenda',
            'with_front' => true ),
            'has_archive' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'show_in_rest' => true,

            'supports' => array( 'title', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'revisions', 'page-attributes')
        )
    );

    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'agenda');
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'agenda');
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_agenda');
```

Now I've already managed to rewrite the slug for the post types with the following function:

**Function:**

```
function school_post_type_link($link, $post) {

      if ($post->post_type == 'agenda') {

            if ($school = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'category')) {


                $link = str_replace('%school%', array_pop($school)->slug, $link);

                return $link;
            }

    } elseif ($post->post_type == 'vacatures') {

        if ($school = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'category')) {

            $link = str_replace('%school%', array_pop($school)->slug, $link);

            return $link;
        }

        } elseif ($post->post_type == 'schoolgids') {

            if ($school = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'category')) {

                $link = str_replace('%school%', array_pop($school)->slug, $link);

                return $link;
            }

    } else {
        return $link;
    }
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'school_post_type_link', 1, 3);
```

This way, I replace the '%school%' for the for the category name. And it seem to work:

[image: screenshot-of-image-structure-working]

So what I'm basicly doing is, checking if the post type is one of my custom post types, and if so, I replace the slug of it.

Now when I click view page, I keep getting the page not found (404) page. I have no idea why this is, because I can edit the post in WordPress itself without any problems.

Any idea what could cause this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you flushed the rewrite rules? Just visit the Permalink Settings page.

Comment: @SallyCJ Yes, everytime I change something

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really notice the rewrite structure. But see my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error 404 happens because you haven't registered the `%school%` rewrite *tag* — you need to register it so that WordPress will know what to replace it with when generating the rewrite rules — i.e. it doesn't remain as `%school%` in the generated rewrite rules. And you can register the tag using [`add_rewrite_tag()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_tag/):

```php
// Add this to custom_post_agenda(), before you call register_post_type().
add_rewrite_tag( '%school%', '([^/]+)' );
```

Secondly, when you register the post type, the `has_archive` should be set to a unique slug such as `agendas` and not just `true` because if you use `'has_archive' => true`, the archive slug would be `%school%`:

```php
register_post_type( 'agenda', array(
    'has_archive' => 'agendas',
    // ...
) );
```

And third, because the post type's rewrite slug starts with the `([^/]+)` (i.e. a category slug), you need the following filter to remove unnecessary rewrite rules (for that post type) which will conflict with Page's (and possibly other post types' and/or taxonomies') rewrite rules:

```php
// Add this after custom_post_agenda() or somewhere else where appropriate.
add_filter( 'agenda_rewrite_rules', function( $rules ){
    // Remove all rules which don't have "/agenda/".
    unset( $rules['([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$'] );
    unset( $rules['([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$'] );
    unset( $rules['([^/]+)/?$'] );

    return $rules;
} );
```

### UPDATE

I forgot to mention that you need to apply the above filter (i.e. `<post type>_rewrite_rules`) to other post types with the same rewrite slug format (`%school%/<post type>` like `%school%/agenda`). So remove the above code from your functions file and use this instead:

```php
function fix_school_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
    // Remove all rules which don't have "/<post type>/".
    unset( $rules['([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$'] );
    unset( $rules['([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$'] );
    unset( $rules['([^/]+)/?$'] );

    return $rules;
}
add_filter( 'agenda_rewrite_rules', 'fix_school_rewrite_rules' );     // for "agenda" CPT
add_filter( 'vacatures_rewrite_rules', 'fix_school_rewrite_rules' );  // for "vacatures" CPT
add_filter( 'schoolgids_rewrite_rules', 'fix_school_rewrite_rules' ); // for "schoolgids" CPT
```

And don't forget to flush the rewrite rules. And once again, for each CPT, the `has_archive` should be set to a unique slug.

Comment: Hi Sally, this works great, thanks! 
Didn't know I had to add the rewrite rule for this. But your explanation makes sense :)

Thanks again!

Comment: It seems that the school name (set by %school%) now redirects to the index.php. It ignores my template (template-school.php) and also the page.php. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Do you actually have a custom *taxonomy* with the slug `school`? Can you show the code that you use to register the taxonomy?

Comment: This is the default category taxonomy, renamed (labels only) to school(s). I register this in the custom post types with: 

`register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'agenda');`

Comment: Ok, so I suppose the `template-school.php` is a custom Page template? (means you've got something like `Template Name: My Template` in the template) And on what Page are you using that template?

Comment: Yes, the template is called `template-school.php`. The schools are 2 pages with the same name as the category taxonomy. So the taxonomy names are the same as the page names.

Comment: Check the "UPDATE" part in the answer.

Comment: Hi Sally, this did the trick! I also didn't see it...
Again, thanks a 1000 times!